# Integer.parseInt is best way to convert String to Int in Java?

Tags: java

We normally use Integer.parseInt method for `String` to `Integer` conversion in `JAVA`, but when I check the implementation of parseInt method it goes way deep that I think initially. Below I m sharing how deep parseInt goes:

```
Integer.parseInt(String s) ->  Integer.parseInt(String s, int radix) ->  Character.digit(char ch, int radix) -> Character.digit(int codePoint, int radix) -> (Based on instance call will go to digit(int ch, int radix))
```

Note: There are total 7 different Instance define for CharacterData, and one of them will peak for digit.

As per above details it's look like ParseInt is not that easy what it look initially, so will it be not best to convert String to Integer?

However, I followed one discussion (link I lost at moment) and found below method which is pretty fast in terms of performance.

```
 static int getNumber(String number){

     int result = 0;
     int startIndex = 0;


     for(int i=startIndex;i<number.length();i++){
         result = result*10+number.charAt(i)-'0';
     }



    return result;
}
```

and below is the performance test result which I found for both methods.

```
 Value :123456789 , Integer->parseInt Converted in 22000 nanosec.
 Value :123456789 , getNumber Converted in 5000 nanosec.
```

So what will be the best way to convert String to Integer, Integer.parseInt or getNumber method ?

Comment: Hint: what does your method do for the string "this isn't a number" and what do you think it should do?

Comment: how does your getNumber method react if I pass "123456785554548884545412212558454545" ? or if I pass "aa" ?

Comment: Do you have any evidence that Integer.parseInt is affecting the overall performance of your program?  Due to Java’s runtime optimization, a benchmark is not as simple as just printing out the time before and after execution.

Comment: @JonSkeet in my case It will always receive numeric value for my method, but yeah I check that it will compute hex associated for that char if, any of those value pass to getNumber method, But if we pass only numeric value then which method will best to use ?

Comment: @Simmant does it really matter? There are way slower parts in your code than parsing a `String` to an `int`. You're micro-optimizing something that is irrelevant to the speed of your program. As you're a beginner, you should concentrate on correctness instead of speed.

Comment: @VGR please check test result which I posted in my method.

Comment: @Simmant: So you've written your own code which will silently give invalid results rather than throw an exception on error... you've got more code to maintain, and it's more error-prone. Sometimes that *might* be appropriate - but only when you've proven that integer parsing is actually a bottleneck in your application. Have you proven that yet?

Comment: @Kayaman, I agree for one case but what if we have more then 1000 places where we are using same method, because application where I m working on I seen more then 1000 calls for this method. And that's reason I m looking for it's optimizing.

Comment: @Simmant just because you've seen 1000 calls, doesn't make it a performance hotspot. You would need to use a profiler to see what parts can be improved, instead of guessing. If you have 1000 calls that take 22000 nanoseconds, it's nothing compared to 10 calls that take 10 seconds. It's the overall performance that matters.

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry for delay in response, I tried gathering possible details for application with sampler and profiler option available with JDK in built tool Jvisualvm. But when I hit profiler it won't working due my system configuration, so I try with sampler option and that gave meruntime details about classes, memory consumption, cpu utilization etc but method information is not available with sampler option.

Comment: And I found Integer in top classes list when I run my testbed for application, but I m not able get information for respective method.

Answer (score 3):

[`parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,int)) is the way to go. The [Integer documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String)) says

> Use parseInt(String) to convert a string to a int primitive, or use valueOf(String) to convert a string to an Integer object.

`parseInt` is likely to cover a lot of edge cases that you haven't considered with your own code. It has been well tested in production by a lot of users.

Comment: As an aside, sometimes `Integer.parseUnsignedInt()` can be preferable.  For example, if you want to set every bit to `1`, then `Integer.parseInt("FFFFFFFF", 16)` will throw a `NumberFormatException`, but `Integer.parseUnsignedInt("FFFFFFFF", 16)` will return the desired value of `-1`.

Answer (score 1):

I invite you [to look at the source code of the parseInt function](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java#l532). Your naïve function is faster, but it also does way less. Edge cases, such as the number being to large to fit into an `int` or not even being a number at all, will produce undetectable bogus results with your simple function.

It is better to just trust that the language designers have done their job and have produced a reasonably fast implementation of parsing integers. Real optimization is probably elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks you should follow the language designers said, as we know that, if use the getNumber method, it can't detect error when the string don't contain a number character.
also can see [convert-string-to-int](https://www.asenview.com/convert-string-to-int-in-java/)

Answer (score 0):

We can use below java 8 code to convert a string to integer

```
String str33 ="1234";
int xxuu = Stream.of(str33).map(Integer::valueOf).findAny().get();
int xxuu = Stream.of(str33).map(Integer::parseInt).findAny().get();
```